# How to replace the string of the file if matches

Tags: python

I have 2 inputs and one file.txt

file.txt have below lines

```
A1|books|cloths|
A2|color|pencil|
A3|ball|
```

input1,input2

- input1 has to select which line has to add  (A1,A2 or A3)
- input2 has to select what string has to added

input1=A2, input2=|pen|

then my expected file.txt is

```
A1|books|cloths|
A2|color|pen|
A3|ball|
```

`notice that pencil is replace with pen`

Code is below which will add at the last part of the file

```
def func(filename,a,b):
    txt1,txt2="",""
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        txt1 =f.readline().strip()
        while(txt1):
            if a==txt1[:len(a)]:
                txt1+=b
            txt2+=txt1+'\n'
            txt1=f.readline().strip()
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        f.write(txt2)

func("file.txt","A2","pen")
```

Comment: What's your expected output when `input1=A3, input2=foo`?

Comment: @AlenSThomas, yes i am trying to replace last element

Comment: So what you'd like to do is replace the last item on that line with the input you receive from input2?
Also your sample outputs don't match what you're trying to say. So could you please elaborate? Cause the last line doesn't seem to have a trailing '|'

Comment: @AlenSThomas, i have updated the argument (a), if A2 is the input then it will change the A2 last part of line, now the program will be just adding not replacing

Comment: @ShubhamSharma then ball replace with foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way you can do is to insert into the arguments what to replace (i.e. pencil in this case) and then use replace() to replace "pencil" with "pen" and that will give you something like:

```
def func(filename,a,b,c):
    txt1,txt2="",""
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        txt1 =f.readline().strip()
        while(txt1):
            if a==txt1[:len(a)]:
                txt1.replace(c,b)
            txt2+=txt1+'\n'
            txt1=f.readline().strip()
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        f.write(txt2)

func("file.txt","A2","pen","pencil")
```

If you want to replace by last index then do this:

```
def func(filename,a,b):
    txt1,txt2="",""
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        txt1 =f.readline().strip()
        while(txt1):
            if a==txt1[:len(a)]:
                x = txt1.split("|")[:-2] # take out first 2 ["A2","Color"]
                x.append(b) #add "pen" so now ["A2","Color","Pen"]
                txt1 = "|".join(x) #join them into string
                txt1 += "|" #Add another "|" at end of string
            txt2+=txt1+'\n'
            txt1=f.readline().strip()
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        f.write(txt2)

func("file.txt","A2","pen")
```